# $(- 4 + 4 \beta- 3 \beta^2)^{- 1}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{8}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a small problem, where I would heavily aprreciate your help.

Well the question is right in the Title:
What is: $$(- 4 + 4 \beta- 3 \beta^2)^{-1}$$ in $\mathbb{F}_{8}$ in Standard Notation.

Definitions:
$\mathbb{F}_{8}:= \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]/(X^3 + X + 1)$ and $β := [X]_{X^3+X+1}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2}:= \mathbb{Z}/2$

Well I know that:
$$(- 4 + 4 \beta- 3 \beta^2)^{-1} * x = 1$$

But have no clue how figure out the solultion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is the following: Calculate the gcd of $X^3 + X + 1$ (the modulus polynomial) an $-3X^2 + 4X - 4 = X^2\in \mathbf F_2[X]$ with the extended Euclidian algorithm. This gives you polynomials $a(X)$, $b(X)$ with 
$$ (X^3 + X + 1)a(X) + X^2 b(X) = 1 $$
In $\mathbf F_8$ this reads 
$$  \beta^2 b(\beta) = 1 $$
Hence 
$$ (-3\beta^2  + 4\beta - 4)^{-1} = \beta^{-2} = b(\beta).$$

---

We have \begin{align*}
  X^3 + X + 1 &= X \cdot X^2 + (X+1)\\
           X^2 &= X \cdot (X+1) - X\\
           X+1 &= 1 \cdot X + 1\\
\text{Hence, } 1 &= (X+1) - X\\
                 &= (X+1) + X^2 - X\cdot (X+1)\\
                 &= (1-X)\cdot (X+1) + X^2 \\
                 &= (1-X)(X^3 + X+1) - (X-X^2)X^2 + X^2\\
                 &= (1-X)(X^3 + X+ 1) + (1 - X + X^2)X^2 
\end{align*}
So $b(X) = 1 - X + X^2 = 1 + X + X^2 \in \mathbf F_2[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that martini gives the general way to approach such a question: use the extended Euclidean algorithm.

In this particular case, you can get away with a quicker computation, mostly because everything is over ${\mathbb F}_2$, so $2 = 0$ and $-1 = +1$.

As martini already noted,
$$-3\beta^2 + 4\beta - 4 = \beta^2.$$
Now because $\beta^3 + \beta + 1 = 0$, you also get
$$\beta(\beta^2 + 1) = 1.$$
This means that
$$\beta^{-1} = \beta^2 + 1$$
and by squaring you get
$$\beta^{-2} = (\beta^2 + 1)^2 = \beta^4 + 1 = \beta\beta^3 + 1 = \beta (\beta + 1) + 1 = \beta^2 + \beta + 1.$$